# How two Java network servers can share one IP

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, networking, network-protocols

I want to create Java Network servers which share one IP address. Something like the [Piranha](http://www.linuxvirtualserver.org/docs/ha/piranha.html) cluster:

[image: http://www.linuxvirtualserver.org/docs/ha/piranha.jpg]

Is there any solution similar to this?

P.S They have to work as a cluster. If one server is down the second one should handle the traffic.

Comment: So you want to use your two servers for load balancing/fail-over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the obvious solution would be to try to build your Java servers behind the Piranha layer; i.e. implement the application services on "real server 1", "real server 2", etcetera in Java

I'm pretty sure that you can't implement a Piranha-like solution in (pure) Java.  The IP level load balancing is implemented in the network stack in the OS kernel (I think) of the "director".  That rules out (pure) Java for two reasons:

- It is impractical to put Java code inside the kernel.
- To do it in user space in Java would entail using native code to read and write raw network packets.  That is not possible in pure Java.

Besides, the chances are that you'd get better network throughput if the director layer was not implemented in Java, pure or otherwise.

Of course, there are *other* ways to do load balancing as well ...

Answer (score 1):

Just create your standalone tcp/ip servers to listen on different ports (and ofcourse the IP address would be same as this is your requirement)

Comment: Yes but I want the two servers to offer the same web service (for example web pages)?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by 'same' web service. If the both the servers invoke the same instance of web service then both your servers would just invoke that webservice by using URL/URLConnection objects.